# Cannot add a 2012 server to a 2003 domain as it says forrest functional level is 2003 but domains and trusts shows it as 2003

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a single 2003 DC (Enterprise edition 32 bit SP2) that according to AD Domains and Trusts is at functional level Windows Server 2003.

According to AD Users and Computers my Domain functional level is also 2003.

However when I try add a 2012 R2 server as a domain controller on the domain it gives an error "Verification of replica failed. The forest functional level is Windows 2003"

When I run adfind -rootdse forestfunctionality I get back that it is 0 [Windows 2000 Forest Mode]

How do I get my current 2003 setup to correctly be on 2003 Forest Functional level so I can add in my 2012 Domain controller.

[image: Screen shot of AD Domains and Trust current level]

Comment: Do you have multiple domains?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rob, the other two answers are correct. I think you have missed the difference between where you are clicking. See the screen shots below.

Forest: Right Click at the very top
[image]

Domain: Right click on the domain name
[image]

Comment: Thank you - its true a picture is worth a 1000 words - you have resolved my issue

Answer (score 8):

Forest and Domain are two separate things.

Open the Active Directory Domains and Trusts MMC. Right-click on the top node in the tree (Active Directory Domains and Trusts [yourdc]) and pick "Raise Forest Functional Level...".

Comment: I agree forrest and domain are different - I have now added a picture so you can see it says I am at Server 2003 level yet my 2012 still thinks I am at 2000 level - any more suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

> To raise the forest functional level
>
> 1. Open Active Directory Domains and Trusts.
> 2. In the console tree, right-click the Active Directory Domains and Trusts node, and then click Raise Forest Functional Level.
> 3. In Select an available forest functional level, click Windows Server 2003, and then click Raise.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780862%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: I have now added a picture so you can see it says I am at Server 2003 level yet my 2012 still thinks I am at 2000 level - any more suggestions?

Comment: You are clicking the wrong node. Click on "Active Directory Domains and Trusts" not "domain.local"

Comment: Thank you - you are correct - just had to move my mouse up a smidge - appreciate your help.